# Why am I getting Unreachable code detected error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a class that checks when `p` will be equal to `p0`. But I keep getting warning `CS0162: Unreachable code detected` and error `CS0161: 'Arge.NbYear(int, double, int, int)': not all code paths return a value.` I trying changing the control statements but I can't get it right.

```
class Arge
{
    public static int NbYear(int p0, double percent, int aug, int p)
    {
        // your code
        double percent_div = (percent <= 0.0) ? 0.0 : percent / 100.0;

        if (p0 < p)
        {
            for (int count = 0; p0 > p; count++)
            {
                var annual_increase = p0 * percent_div + aug;
                int annual_inc = Convert.ToInt32(annual_increase);

                p0 = p0 + annual_inc;

                return count;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: You first check if ```p0 < p```. Then when it is true, you run the ```for``` loop, but that only runs while ```p0 > p```, so it never will run, because you're only ever getting to that part of the code on the assumption that ```p0 > p``` *isn't* true. Therefore, you have unreachable code.

Comment: Because, in if condition you are returning value in for loop. You should be create a new variable and assign the count to this variable and return it under the for loop.

Comment: And if you would enter the loop (you can't because of the if) it would be an endless loop, because the loop condition is `p0 > p`. So if this is true in the begining, you are always increasing `p0` and never changing `p`. So this condition won't become false anymore.

Comment: @Harith: That's not why it's unreachable. The compiler doesn't (and isn't meant to) perform that sort of check.

Comment: @JonSkeet perhaps not - but I believe I'm right in saying that, compiler warning or not, there's no way to reach that code block, hence it's unreachable.

Comment: @Harith: It's not unreachable code in the language specification meaning of the term. There are lots of ways of constructing code that will never actually be reached, but my reading is that the question isn't about that.

Comment: @Harith if `p0 <  p` the code block is reachable, so I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: @insane_developer the ```for``` loop will never run if ```p0 < p```. There seems to be a misunderstanding of what I mean - the condition of the ```for``` loop is contradicted by the condition of the ```if``` statement you need to pass to get there in the first place, so the code *within the* ```for``` *loop* is redundant - it never runs.

Comment: @Harith yes, that was a misunderstanding, or tunnel vision on my part.

Comment: The unreachable code is the `count++` statement in the for loop, see below.

Comment: `for(..) { .. return }` that "return" will be executed on the first iteration, preventing a second (and further) iteration. This is (probably) an error, but not the one the compiler is complaining about

Comment: @HansKeﬆing: Actually, that's the unreachable code.  Remember that a for loop has three sub-statements: The first runs before the first time in the loop to initialize things.  The second is a bool that is checked before each pass through the loop.  The third part is run after each pass through the loop.  Since the code in the loop never completes, that 3rd statement (`count++`) is never going to execute.  The compiler tags it with "unreachable".  The warning points exactly to that code.  If you have Resharper, it highlights it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *unreachable code* is the `count++` statement in the `for` loop.  Since you `return count;` on each pass through the `for` loop (including, of course, the first pass), then the third part of the `for` loop's statement will never be executed.

The *Not all code paths return a value* error is because you have this structure:

```
if (condition) {
    for (blah-blah) {
        //code
        return count;
    }
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

If the conditions for the `if` statement are met, but those for entering the `for` loop are not met, then then program execution will skip the `for` loop and the program won't hit a return statement.

**Please:** When you report an error, report where the error occurs.  Those 4 numbers in parentheses after the file name (and before the error statement) tell you exactly where the error is.  In this case, for example, the numbers point to the line number and the start and end of the code in error.  My copy/paste of your code gave me this:

```
C:\Develop-Toss\TestConsole\TestConsole\Program.cs(137,45,137,50): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
```

The error started at line 137, character position 45 (the `c` in `count++` and ended at line 137, character position 50 (the first `+` in `count++`)

Your faulty logic (`if (p0 < p) { for (int count = 0; p0 > p; count++) ...`) (i.e., that your code will never enter the `for` loop) isn't the error.  Once you fix the compilation errors, you'll need to fix the logic.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this scenario when for loop won't run at all, then what is expected to be returned from this method? Compiler is saying the same thing because it cannot find any logical flow to return any value if flow never goes inside for loop.

Solution can be either puting return statement after for loop or add return statement at the end of method or remove else clause and simply put return statement over there.(logically I would suggest removing else clause and simply returning 0)

Edit: Simple example of commenting out else statement https://dotnetfiddle.net/Oywe1x (pardon my low quality edit as I am replying with mobile phone)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (p0 < p)
        {
            for (int count = 0; p0 > p; count++) // this will not loop at all
            {
                var annual_increase = p0 * percent_div + aug;
                int annual_inc = Convert.ToInt32(annual_increase);

                p0 = p0 + annual_inc;

                return count;
            }
        }
```

The if statement is saying `p0 < p`, and the inner for loop is saying `p0 > p`, so that is why it's unreachable. It will never make it to the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public static int NbYear(int p0, double percent, int aug, int p)
{
    // your code
    double percent_div = (percent <= 0.0) ? 0.0 : percent / 100.0;

    var count = 0;

    while (p0 > p);
    {
        var annual_increase = p0 * percent_div + aug;
        int annual_inc = Convert.ToInt32(annual_increase);
        p0 = p0 + annual_inc;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained what you changed and more important *why*

Comment: It's better to give a fishing rod to a hungry man, not a fish.

Comment: `It's better to give a fishing rod to a hungry man, not a fish.` But you gave the fish, _not_ the fishing rod. It is also not 100% clear with your new code how `p0` will ever cease being greater than `p` since you keep increasing its value. Unless `annual_increase` is negative - in which case the variable naming should be improved.